# How to enable a menu in Eclipse depending on the EXE file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to disable a context menu item in Eclipse plugin bases on the EXE file. I mean, I want to enable the menu only when my EXE file is installed in the user's system. Otherwise it should be in disable mode. What is the way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are no easy way to do this.

The normal options are

- have a special option in the test system (which can be spoofed...)
- have a `PropertyTester` that can test some special different between the systems

The first option is very easy, but can also easily be spoofed.

To do the later, you must

- create and declare a `PropertyTester`
- add a `activeWhen` or `visibleWhen` expression to the relevant menu entries, which use `test` expression element to get the value from the property tester

Comment: I have tried to do with property tester But it seems that this code is never called.It is my Plugin xml.

Comment: I have tried to do with property tester But it seems that this code is never called.It is my Plugin xml.<extension point = "org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus"><action id="org.eclipse.ui.contextmenu.Open"<test forcePluginActivation="true" property="com.my.canOpen" value="true">
 </test> </action></objectContribution></extension>
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
<propertyTester id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.IResourceTester" type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource" namespace="com.my"
properties="canOpen" class="com.PropertyTester" </propertyTester></extension></plugin>

Comment: Yes ,But i dnt knw Why its not working.I am using objectcontribution for context menu.Does it make any difference?

Comment: Using  `objectContribution` should not make a difference. Personally, I always use the `menus` extension point with the `locationURI` `org.eclipse.ui.popup.any`...

Comment: Use your own ID for your property tester.  What you've written would collide with one already provided from JDT: org.eclipse.jdt.ui.IResourceTester.

Comment: @nitind is absolutely right: never reuse an ID!!! Though look at the code for expression handling in `TypeExtensionManager` it does not seem to matter in this case...